# How to solve for this recurrence T(n) = T(n − 1) + lg(1 + 1/n), T(1) = 1?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I got stuck in this recurrence:

```
T(n) = T(n − 1) + lg(1 + 1/n), T(1) = 1?
```

for a while and it seems the master method cannot be applied on this one.

Comment: I may be wrong, but for me it seems like it is linear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have:

`lg(1 + 1/n) = lg((n + 1) / n) = lg(n+1) - lg(n)`

Hence:

`T(n) - T(n - 1) = lg(n + 1) - lg(n)`

`T(n-1) - T(n - 2) = lg(n) - lg(n - 1)`

`...`

`T(3) - T(2) = lg(3) - lg(2)`

`T(2) - T(1) = lg(2) - lg(1)`

Adding and eliminating, we get:

`T(n) - T(1) = lg(n + 1) - lg(1) = lg(n + 1)`

or `T(n) = 1 + lg(n + 1)`

Hence `T(n) = O(lg(n))`

Comment: I agree for a computer (and I am not the one who has downvoted your answer), but then the equation is fundamentally incorrect. If it should be valid on an algorithmic basic on a _Computer_, it should be rewritten as `T(n) = T(n - 1) + lg(1 + 1/n) + k` where `k` is a constant or `O(1)`. In that case, the solution will turn out to be `T(n) = n * k + lg(n + 1)` or `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as the other correct answer here, just proved differently.

All the following equations are created from the given recurrence:

- T(n)  = T(n-1) + Log((n+1)/n)
- T(n-1) = T(n-2) + Log(n/(n-1))
- .
- .
- .
- T(2) = T(1) + Log(3/2)

Summing all RHS and LHS in the above equations results in:

- T(n) = T(1) + Log(3/2) + Log(4/3) + ... + Log((n+1)/n)

Since Log(a) + Log(b) = Log(ab),

- T(n) = 1 + Log((n+1)/2)
- T(n) = Log(10) + Log((n+1)/2) = Log(5n + 5) assuming that base was 10 and using 1 = Log<sub>10</sub>10

Therefore T(n) = O(Log(5n + 5)) = O(Log(n))

Answer (score 1):

It is not linear as some people claim. It is `O(log(n))`. Here is mathematical analysis:

---

If you will start unrolling recursion you will get:

[image]

if you will do this till the end you will have

[image]

or in a short form:

[image]

Once you approximate the sum with an integral, you will get:

[image]

Finally if you will take a limit x -> infinity:

You will see that the first part is [image]

Which gives you a final solution `log(x + 1)` which is `O(log(n))`

Comment: The summation has a closed form solution for finite `n` outside the limit in this case.

Comment: @user1952500 :-) this is embarrasing. Anyway there is nothing wrong with this solution apart from it overcomplicates things. It can also show what to do if there is no close form solution

Comment: no worries. I was about to proceed the same route as the limit allows us to quickly compute the solution mentally. Just tried out the other way :)