# How to solve the recurrence T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4), T(1) = 0, T(2) = 1 is T(n) = Θ(n lg φ ), where φ is the golden ratio?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I tried recursion tree method since the master method is not applicable for this recurrence but it seems that it is not the right method also, any help would be appreciated !

Comment: no, I am new to algorithm design and analysis I just want to expand my knowledge. Since I cannot afford to go to college and ask a professor for help maybe here someone can help? have a nice day :)

Comment: n = 
     n/2            n/4 =  2n/4 + n/4 = 3n/4 
n/4  n/4        n/16 =  n/16 n/4 + n/4 + n/16 + n/16 = 10n/16

I tried the recursion tree but i believe geometric series wont be applicable since it is not n^2(correct me if im wrong). and I think that this problem has a particular algorithm to apply that is why i asked for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either I have an error somewhere in my derivation or there is an error in your statement.

---

You do this by unrolling the recursion:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/4) = 2T(n/4) + T(n/8) 
T(n) = 3T(n/8) + 2T(n/16)
T(n) = 5T(n/16) + 3T(n/32)
....
T(n) = F(i + 1)T(n/2^(i-1)) + F(i)T(n/2^i)
```

where `F(i)` if a [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Using boundary condition `T(n/2^i) = T(1)` have `n = 2^i` -> `i = log2(n)`.

`T(n) = F(log2(n) + 1) T(2) + F(log2(n)) T(1)` which is equal `F(log2(n) + 1)`

Now using this formula:

[image]

and stripping it to only `phi^n` (square root of 5 has nothing to do with complexity and the second `thi^n -> 0` if `n->inf`) you will get:

`T(n) = phi^(log2(n)+1) = phi * phi^log2(n)` which is equal to `O(n^log2(phi))`, where `log2(phi) = 0.694`.

**P.S.** Look at it as a hint or a suggestion. Now you do not need college or a professor to learn something. Determination and perseverance is more important. Do not be afraid to try doing something. You already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34148070/1090562) and claimed to try master method where you failed. People suggested you a completely different approach and here you claim that you tried completely the sam and have not tried the method that worked in a previous case.

Comment: Thanks for answering and for the advice. that is true, I just want someone to explain and show the steps/procedures thoroughly and simple to understand it better. Do not worry i am studying the solutions people gave me because that is why i am here in the first place for the procedures. Have a great day ahead  :)